# Swift - UITableViewController with navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am facing an issue with one of my table view controllers. I don't seem to be able to get the navigation bar to show on top no matter what option I enable (maybe I am missing something).

I tried the following:

- Selecting the controller in storyboard and going to attributes inspector and ensuring that top bar is set to Translucent Navigation (didn't work)
- In the viewWillAppear function, I wrote: (didn't work)

> self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

Attached is also an image of the controller discussed. How can I do show the top bar? otherwise the results are ugly since the records showing (rows) are starting from the very top. I do not wish to use UIEdgeInsetsMake to fix it if possible.

[image]

and

[image]
Thanks,

[image]

Comment: How do you present the view?

Comment: please clarify what you are asking...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click the `ordersViewController`. Then in the top bar *Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller* and remove the `navigationbar` you currently have in the VC.

Comment: that leads to a loop whereby the view controller is populated repeatedly (leading to a crash probably).

Comment: It shouldn't. The only thing you did is embed your VC in a Navigation Controller. AFAIK, this is the way to do it though.

Comment: it worked. The issue was that I didn't remove the code suggested by another user. Thanks a bunch

Comment: I don't think this actually works. It adds a UINavigationBarItem, not a UINavigationBar

Answer (score 5):

If you are coming from another controller to `TableViewController` then

try this code

```
let nav : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourControllerName") as UIViewController)

self.navigationController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I have tab bar and one of them is order tab...so when I click it, the first picture above is loaded (the view controller that is)

Comment: "the first picture above is loaded (the view controller that is)" is it a tableViewController ?

Comment: @ksa_coder can't see picture. might be stackoverflow issue

Comment: well I think others see it...sorry can't do much about it

Answer (score 4):

You have to embed your `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: This is the best solution if you are using Storyboard. But if your UITableViewController is in a xib, then use the above solution from hellosheikh.